# How and where is the "head" list initialized?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

How and where is the head list implemented in task 83 on leetcode? Where is it initialized? Can you please write the code for this in what it would look like in a regular editor?

Here is the solution:

```
public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    if(head==null || head.next==null)return head;
        ListNode node=head;       
         while(head!=null && head.next!=null){
           if(head.val==head.next.val){
              head.next=head.next.next;
            }
           else head=head.next;
         }      
    return node;`
}
```

Comment: `head` is passed into `deleteDuplicates` by whoever called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How and where is the `head` list implemented

In Computer science, the first Node of a Linked list is usually called the *head* (*see: [Linked list - Basic concepts and nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Basic_concepts_and_nomenclature)*).

And *head* an instance of `Node` class (*a building block of the Linked list data structure*), like any other node.

Method `deleteDuplicates()` expects an instance of `Node` which should be provided by the caller (i.e. a part of the code that uses `deleteDuplicates()`).

And by the way, it's a good practice to avoid mutating arguments, therefore it would be cleaner to use `node` reference to iterate through the list and preserve the `head` intact. This way it's more obvious that method returns precisely the same reference to the beginning of the list that has been passed to it.

```
public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) return head;
    ListNode node = head;

    while (node != null && node.next != null) {
        if (node.val == node.next.val) {
            node.next = node.next.next;
        } else node = node.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: what is next field?

Comment: @DavidMSK Judging by the code, `Node` class should contain at least two fields: `ListNode next` and `value` (of whatever type).  I.e. each node has its own value and a reference to the next Node in the list. Take a look at the link to the Wiki (it contain an illustrated explanation of how Linked list works).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first example, the calling code might look like this:

```
ListNode source = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2)));

ListNode result = new Solution().deleteDuplicates(source);

// code that checks that result is a list of two elements and contains 1 and 2 in that order
```